# Android Firestore remove child with where clause

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

I have a database 'Notifications' in firestore. I want to delete certain child based on a condition (say when the type is postlike). Please note that I want the answer in JAVA, not KOTLIN.

The db is like this:

```
Notifications
              someid1
              someid2
              someid3
              someid4 -> type:= "postlike"
                         userid:= "uk1we34hjkshej22e"
                         text:= "//null//"
              someid5
              someid6
```

I have tried with query like this:

```
 Query query = db.collection("Notifications")
                                        .whereEqualTo("type", "postlike");
```

But then I couldnt find any way to get and remove it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do for loop to your query results and for each document get reference then delete the document using the document reference

```
db.collection("Notifications")
        .whereEqualTo("type", "postlike").get().addOnCompleteListener {
            task ->
            val querySnapshot = task.result ?: return@addOnCompleteListener
            for (document in querySnapshot.documents){
                document.reference.delete()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. It is what I was looking for